# Laravel 4 Model relation Event?

Tags: php, events, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Are there any events that fire when a new model relation is created? e.g.

```
$comment = Comment::create( array('title' => 'hello world!') );

$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

are there any events that are fired when the comment to post relation is saved? This would be very handy in certain use cases.

As an example in my app i have users and organisations. When i add a user to an organisation:

```
$user->organisations()->save($organisation);
```

i would love this to fire an event where i could bind the user to the organisations permission groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can register Model Observers.

From the docs:

```
class UserObserver {

    public function saving($model)
    {
        //
    }

    public function saved($model)
    {
        //
    }

}


User::observe(new UserObserver);
```

http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-observers

I have never used them, and I am not certain if they are necessary for your scenario, but I think this is the way to go if you really want to do it.